# How do I easily return and API response from my flow to my canvas app in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

Looking for some assistance, I have created a flow and a canvas app in power apps that calls an API, I finally got it to work but seems there has to be an easier way to do this.

In my flow I'm taking the body and parsing it to get just what I need then returning the body of that response to the canvas app. I could bypass that step and just return the body of the Api Call step, but my main question is, it seems a little to much to have to write some regex in my function when I click the button to call my flow.

This creates the collection for me with the correct fields, but is there an easier way for the app to know my schema without having to manually define it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *only* reason you're using Flow is to call the API from Power Apps, then yes, there is an easier way. You can create a [Custom Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-powerapps) and stop using Flow altogether.

**Steps:**

1. From `make.powerapps.com`, click `Dataverse` then `Custom Connectors`
2. Click `+ New custom connector`
3. Click `Create from blank` and name the Custom Connector
4. Enter the `host` url (without the `https://`)

   - Keep the `base url` to `/`
   - [image]
5. Click `Security -->`
6. Select the correct security type

   - You can also select `No authentication` on this screen and use a request header on the `Definition` screen
   - [image]
7. Click `Definition -->`
8. Click `New action` then name the `Summary`, `Description` and `Operation ID`

   - [image]
9. Under `Request` click `+ Import from sample`
10. Select the method (`GET, POST, etc.`), enter the request URL and click `Import`
    -You'll want to paste in an example URL that has ALL required parameters.
    - **Example**: `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&latitude=48.814963&longitude=-122.71135&maxradiuskm=50&orderby=magnitude-asc`

    - [image]
    - **Note**: This is where you could put an `Authorization` header if needed
11. Under `Response` click `Default` then `Import from sample`

    - Paste any required headers and the anticipated (typically JSON) response
    - I like to use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) here...
    - [image]
12. Click `Import`

    - [image]
    - It's pretty nice how Power Apps parses the JSON response. Each of these will be returned to your app. You can edit/delete/etc.
    - [image]
13. At this point, click `Create connector`
14. Scroll down and click `Code preview -->`

    - Don't mess with this unless you know what you're doing
15. Click `Test -->`
16. Click `+ New connection`

    - [image]
17. Depending on how you setup Security for this Custom Connector, you will either:

    - Login using your Windows credentials
    - Paste in an API key
    - Or just click "Create" (as in my example which uses a free API)

      - If you used an Auth header in the `Request` area, this applies too
    - [image]
18. Creating this Connection "kicks you out" of the Custom Connector creation screen. You'll have to click `Custom Connectors`, select the one you just created, then click alllll the way through to the `Test` screen.
19. Once you're there, you should see the Connection has been made.

    - [image]
20. Enter the required parameters and click `Test operation`
21. You should see a Status 200 and the response body shown

    - [image]
    - Pretty much done with the Custom Connector at this point.
22. Back in your Canvas PowerApp, click `Add data` and find the Custom Connector you just created

    - [image]
23. Add a `Button` control and add this to the `OnSelect` property:

```
ClearCollect(colName, 
    'CustomConnectorName'.OperationID(
        {
            required_param1: "text",
            required_param2: 1234,
            required_paramN: "whatever",
        }
    )
)
```

**Actual example**:

```
ClearCollect(colEarthquakes, 
    '2022-11-27_SO_CustomConnector'.GETearthquakes(
        {
            format: "geojson",
            latitude: 48.814963,
            longitude: -122.71135,
            maxradiuskm: 50,
            orderby: "magnitude-asc"
        }
    )
)
```

24. Click the `Button` control and investigate the response the Custom Connector returns. Depending on the shape of the JSON, you may need to "climb into" the nested JSON by using dot-notation in the `ClearCollect()` function.

This will get you close. If you want more, check out this [video](https://youtu.be/Th4tNQJWvUQ?t=401)

**Note:** Custom Connectors are a premium feature. All users of the app will need either a PowerApps per-user or per-app license.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new [Power Platform CLI command](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automatically-create-a-power-app-from-a-rest-api/) that will automatically create a Power App from a REST API.

[image]

[image]